# I have declared a Session object which contains a List of objects but can't iterate through it

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I didn't include all the code, **I am getting the row successfully**, but I don't know if I am adding it correctly to the SESSION or if I'm just iterating wrong through it.

```
             // Obtaining GridView's desired row
                int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];

                // Create Session object as a List of GridViewRows
                var aux = Session["carrito"] as List<GridViewRow>;
                if (aux == null) aux = new List<GridViewRow>();

                // Adding the row to my SESSION
                aux.Add(row);
```

Imagine that I'm adding multiple rows (the way it works is that I press a button on the GridView and I add that row to the SESSION).
The thing is, when I try to iterate through my SESSION Object on another ASPX.CS it says that my Session is null. Here is the code:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (var aux in Session["carrito"] as List<GridViewRow>)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(aux);
        }

        // We add it to the GridView
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: In the first example, when Session doesn't contain your list, you create a list but then you forget to add that list back to the Session. So Session["carrito"] is still null

Comment: It makes sense! I'll try that
Can you tell me if I am iterating through it the right way in the second code block?

Comment: No, that's not correct. You are looping over a List of GridViewRow and trying to add them to a datatable rows collection. This will not work as you think. You need to define the DataTable columns and their type, then in the Rows.Add you need to pass an array of values for a single DataTable row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Session problem is caused by not adding a valid collection of GridViewRow when you find that there is no value for your Session entry

```
var aux = Session["carrito"] as List<GridViewRow>;
if (aux == null) 
{
    aux = new List<GridViewRow>();
    Session["carrito"] = aux;
}
```

but then there is another problem in the second part of your code. Here the code loops over a List of GridViewRow and tries to add every object in the list to a datatable rows collection. This will not work. You need to define the DataTable columns and their type, then in the Rows.Add you need to pass an array of values for a single DataTable row.

So suppose that every GridViewRow contains the information about a Customer Name and a Customer Phone Number in two cells. The datatable needs to have two columns like this

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("CustName", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("CustPhone", typeof(string));
```

Now you can extract the information from your GridViewRow and create a DataRow for the table

```
    List<GridViewRow> rows = Session["carrito"] as List<GridViewRow>;
    foreach (var aux in rows)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {aux.Cells[0].Text, aux.Cells[1].Text});
    }

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Huge thanks!

Just one last question: after I do aux.Add(row) in the first block of code, do I need to then do Session["carrito"] = aux again?

Comment: No because both the Session entry and the aux variable contain a reference to the same List object in memory and if you modify the content of the list the two references will both see the changes. But do you really need all this GridViewRow juggling? It is not feasible to store directly the DataTable in the session?

Comment: Thanks! I'll tel you: What I'm trying to do is a Web Page in which I have all the products on one page and the Cart on another page. Basically when I click the button "Add To Cart" I need to get the values from THAT ROW (on which the button has been clicked) and pass it to a Session so I can use them on  the CART PAGE.
Getting directly the full GridViewRow it's the first and only solution that I've come up with. And that's because I need to display ANOTHER GridView on the Cart Page